# (Odoo) How can i save draft data that i can access later?

Tags: odoo, backend

I am trying to save data of a project specifically its name, type, creation date, end date, and five more attributes. In order to insert all of the attributes, the user needs to go through three-step phases that are present in three separate views. I want the data to be saved as draft data in case the user decides to stop the post creation on the second step. The functionality I am trying to develop is similar to the shopping cart functionality that is present on every e-commerce website.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it is possible!
An alternative would be to group your fields into groups and add a button that controls the visibility of the group of fields. When the user is done filling the first group of fields he can click on the button which will hide the group he filled and show the next group, etc.

Comment: There are forty attributes that need to be filled across all three steps in order to successfully create a project. So that's why I wanted to somehow save the data going from one step to another.

Comment: The data will be saved if you apply the method mentioned